# disable the windows key in parallels 14

Tags: macos, keyboard, windows, parallels-desktop

If I press CMD then the start menu repeatedly flies open.

It is really annoying, so I need to stop this.

How do I disable the windows key in Parallels 14??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Parallels Desktop and go to Preferences > Shortcuts > Windows 10 (or whatever your virtual machine is called, in the Virtual Machines section of the sidebar). Add a new keyboard shortcut and map the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, or something other than <kbd>win</kbd>.

This will definitively stop the Start menu from popping open every time you hit the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key individually, but I'm not sure how it affects other shortcuts that make use of the Windows key.

Comment: sir. I owe you a beer, that was driving me nuts.

Comment: Same! The funny thing is, it never occurred to me that this behavior could even be changed until I came across this question. But then I thought "huh, I wonder what happens if I just remap the Command key by itself to something else." I've been using it this way now for the past two days, and it seems like it doesn't affect any other keyboard shortcuts that _include_ the Command key, just the single key by itself. Which is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore (at least for me) as the windows key is now triggered by doubletapping the CMD key. The shortcuts don't let me define doubletaps.